# How can you determine if a list has an adjacent duplicate?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am attempting to create a function that can determine if the list has adjacent duplicates.

This is what I have so far:

```
def adjacentDups(lst):
    #Add code here
    for i in lst:   
        for x in range(len(lst)):
            if i == lst[x - 1] or lst[x + 1]:   #if the number in the list equals the number before or after
                return True
            else:
                return False

lst = [2,4,3,6,8,5,9,7,5,7]
print(lst)
print(adjacentDups(lst))

##Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
True  #Should be False
```

Comment: Take a minute to read about how to leverage `or` in an `if` statement. Then continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: Will do, appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe your if statement should look like `if i == lst[x-1] or i == lst[x+1]`. You're writing the expression like you'd say it in natural language, like "I want an apple and a pear" rather than "I want an apple and I want a pear." Python needs you to spell it out exactly.

Comment: Your double for loop seems odd (i.e. overly complex for question).  Also, your Output for print(lst) seems incorrect.   Are you just trying to detect if the list has at least one repeat?

Comment: @GavinWood why should the o/p be `false`? should all elements have an adjacent duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You solution kinda works, but it has a few issues. First, you're not making a real comparison. When you do `if i == lst[x - 1] or lst[x + 1]:`, you're not comparing if i is equal to the previous or next number, you're comparing it to the previous number, and then asking if a number `lst[x+1] # returns a number` is True/False. 1 returns True, so having a 1 in the list will cause a false positive.

Also, you're doing a nested loop for no reason, you're going over the list, and then over an index of the list, effectively comparing every number to every other making this less efficient and prone to report false positives, you're also going to return False if at any point any number doesn't fit your criteria, which you wouldn't want to happen. Here's a fixed version of what you did:

```
def adjacentDups(lst):
    # enumerate returns an index starting at 0 and the value of an iterable object
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        # we don't want to access the last member
        # of the list with -1, so we check if it's 0
        # to not go below that
        if index == 0:
            if value == lst[index + 1]:   
                return True
        # same deal here, but with the last element in the list
        elif index == len(lst) - 1:
            if value == lst[index - 1]:
                return True
        # everything in the middle get checked on both sides
        else:
            if value == lst[index - 1] or value == lst[index + 1]:
                return True

    # if none returned True, THEN we return False
    return False

lst = [2,4,3,2,8,5,9,3,5,7]
print(lst)
print(adjacentDups(lst))
```

This works as you expect.

Comment: I don't thing you need to compare it on both sides, you only need to check with the next

Comment: and with a appropriate `zip` you don't need to worry about indices

Comment: @Copperfield True, any number that has a duplicate adjacent to it will raise the `return True` when comparing the next one.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 9]

a = [lst[x] for x in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[x-1]!=lst[x] and lst[x+1]!=lst[x]]
a.append(lst[len(lst)-1])
#print(a)
print('yes' if a != lst else 'No')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am kinda confused.So you want to return True if the previus or the next number is equal to the number in the middle of them?For example if lst = [1,2,2] that should return True? because the index 2 is the same as the index 1?
If thats the case then you can try this one

```
def adjacentDups(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
          if lst[i] == lst[i+1]:
             return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
def adjacent_dups(lst):
    adj = [lst[x] for x in range(len(lst) - 1) if lst[x] == lst[x+1]]
    return len(adj) > 0

lst = [2,4,3,6,8,5,9,7,5,7]
print(adjacent_dups(lst))
# False

lst = [2,4,3,6,8,5,9,5,7,7]
print(adjacent_dups(lst))
# True
```

Note that this does only one comparison for each pair of adjacent elements, instead of two as in your code (the second comparison is redundant).